# Join on two RDDs using Scala in Spark

Tags: arrays, scala, join, apache-spark

I am trying to implement Local Outlier Factor on Spark. So I have a set of points that I read from a file and then for each point find the N nearest neighbors. Each point has an index given to it using zipWithIndex() command

So Now I have two RDDs
Firstly

```
RDD[(Index:Long, Array[(NeighborIndex:Long, Distance:Double)])]
```

Where Long represents its index, and the Array consist of its N nearest neighbors with the Long representing the Index position of these neighbors and Double Representing their Distance from the given point

Second

`RDD[(Index:Long,LocalReachabilityDensity:Double)]`

Here, Long again represents the Index of a given point, and Double represents its Local Reachability density

What I want, is an RDD, which contains all the points, and an array of their N closest neighbors and their Local Reachability density

```
RDD[(Index:Long, Array[(NeighborIndex:Long,LocalReachabilityDensity:Double)])]
```

So basically here, Long would represent the index of a point, and the array would be of its N closest neighbors, with their index values and Local Reachability density.

According to my understanding, I need to run a map on the first RDD, and then join the values in its array with the second RDD that contain the Local Reachability densities, to get Local Reachability density for all the given indexes of its N neighbors. But I am not sure how to achieve this. If any one can help me out that would be great

Comment: Join second with third, then cartesian with first, and filter out far neighbors

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
val rdd1: RDD[(index: Long, Array[(neighborIndex: Long, distance: Double)])] = ...
val rdd2: RDD[(index: Long, localReachabilityDensity: Double)] = ...
```

I really don't like using Scala's `Array` at all. I also don't like that your abstractions are cross-purposes; in other words, `index` in `rdd2` is buried in various entries in `rdd1`. This makes things hard to reason about and also incurs the limitations of the Spark RDD API where you can't access a second RDD while transforming the first. I  believe you should rewrite your current jobs to produce easier abstractions to work with.

But if you must:

```
val flipped = rdd1.map { 
  case (index, array) => 
    array.map {
      case (neighborIndex, distance) => (neighborIndex, (index, distance))
    }.elements.toVector
}.flatMap(identity)
 .groupBy(_._1)
val result = flipped.join(rdd2).mapValues {
   case (indexDistances, localReachabilityDensity) => 
      indexDistances.map {
         case (index, _) => (index, localReachabilityDensity)
      }    
}
```

The basic idea is to flip `rdd1` to  "extract" the  `neighborIndex` values to the top level as the keys of the `PairRDD`, which then allows me to do  a  `join` with `rdd2`. And to replace `Array` with `Vector`. Once you do the join on the same indices, combining things is much easier.

Note that this was off the top of my head and may not be perfect. The idea isn't so much to give you a solution to copy-paste but rather suggest a different direction.

Comment: I am getting an error on .head
value head is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, Double)]

From my understanding, you are using head to get the first element the filter result and then getting its second element (the local reachability density).

I tried using first() instead but got an error that transformation or action cannot be called inside transformation...
So any solutions in mind?

Comment: So i decided to just remove the head to store all the values. And I ran into error that you cannot have transformation inside transformation. The code has a map inside mapValues, which gives the error

`org.apache.spark.SparkException: RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations`

Comment: Even with lookup we get the same error 
`org.apache.spark.SparkException: RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations;`

Comment: You've encountered an RDD limitation I was not aware of since I have never tried to do what you are trying to do. Maybe my latest suggestion will point you in the right direction. The main thing is to reorient your abstractions.